# Altbeacon library foreground mode not working on Android

Tags: android, service, beacon, altbeacon, foreground-service

Hello guys i am using the Altbeacon library to discover beacons to my android application. The service is running in **foreground** mode to workaround the android 8 background services limitations.

**The problem**

When i put my application to background (pressing the home button), despite the scanning still working for a minute, after this interval the *continuous* scanning stops and starts again after 5 minutes

**The Code**

```
public class BoikomApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements BootstrapNotifier, BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier { 
...
 public void startListening() {

    final Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo);
    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.foreground_notification_title));
    builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.foreground_notification_text));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BeaconActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                "Notification Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("Listening for beacons");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            builder.setChannelId(channel.getId());
        }
    }
    beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 456);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(false);
    beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);

    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);

    beaconManager.bind(this);
   }
@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    LoggingHelper.i("[Beacon Service] didEnterRegion");
    BeaconServiceHandler.getInstance().onEnterRegion(region, this);
}
@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d("App", "didExitRegion");
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
    LoggingHelper.i("[Beacon Service] didDetermineStateForRegion");
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this);
    try {
        for (Region region : regions) {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LoggingHelper.e("[Beacon Service] Error while connecting to beacon service", e);
    }
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);
}
@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {
    LoggingHelper.i("[Beacon Service] didRangeBeaconsInRegion");
    BeaconServiceHandler.getInstance().onEnterRegion(region, this);
}
public void stopListening() {
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
    beaconManager.disableForegroundServiceScanning();
}
```

**Logs**

> ```
>   2019-07-20 01:13:35.409 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 89 milliseconds
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.417 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: Set a wakeup alarm to go off in 300000 ms: PendingIntent{69e638a: android.os.BinderProxy@a809dfb}
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.506 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: Done with scan cycle
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.509 13181-13181/package D/ScanHelper: Calling ranging callback
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.509 13181-13181/package D/Callback: attempting callback via local broadcast intent: org.altbeacon.beacon.range_notification
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.514 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: Not stopping scan because this is Android N and we keep scanning for a minimum of 6 seconds at a time. We will stop in 424 millisconds.
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.514 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: starting a new scan cycle
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.514 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: We are already scanning and have been for 904944386 millis
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.514 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 1100 milliseconds
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.522 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: Set a wakeup alarm to go off in 300000 ms: PendingIntent{69e638a: android.os.BinderProxy@a809dfb}
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.522 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: Scan started
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.522 13181-13181/package D/IntentHandler: got ranging data
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.522 13181-13181/package I/Boikom: Thread: main
>             ├ package.core.util.LoggingHelper.i(LoggingHelper.java:84)
>             └ package.BoikomApplication.didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Application.java:133)
>         [Beacon Service] didRangeBeaconsInRegion
>     2019-07-20 01:13:35.523 13181-13181/package W/Boikom: Thread: main
>             ├ package.core.util.LoggingHelper.w(LoggingHelper.java:217)
>             └ package.core.service.BeaconServiceHandler.onEnterRegion(BeaconServiceHandler.java:89)
>         [BeaconServiceHandler] The specified beacon has already show recently. Abort
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.142 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: Done with scan cycle
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.149 13181-13181/package D/ScanHelper: Calling ranging callback
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.155 13181-13181/package D/Callback: attempting callback via local broadcast intent: org.altbeacon.beacon.range_notification
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.159 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: stopping bluetooth le scan
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.159 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: Stopping scan
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.162 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: starting a new scan cycle
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.162 13181-13333/package D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: Stopping LE scan on scan handler
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.164 13181-13333/package D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.164 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: starting a new bluetooth le scan
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.164 13181-13333/package D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.168 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 1100 milliseconds
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.170 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: Set a wakeup alarm to go off in 300000 ms: PendingIntent{69e638a: android.os.BinderProxy@a809dfb}
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.171 13181-13181/package D/CycledLeScanner: Scan started
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.172 13181-13181/package D/StartupBroadcastReceiver: onReceive called in startup broadcast receiver
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.173 13181-13181/package D/StartupBroadcastReceiver: got wake up intent
>     2019-07-20 01:19:25.175 13181-13181/package D/IntentHandler: got ranging data
> ```

Comment: What gets logged at the system level (not just filtering for your app) during the 5 minutes where you are not getting callbacks?  What phone model and OS version is this?

Comment: Hello @davidgyoung too many logs to add here. The development phone is android 8.1, huwei p20. It seems that somehow when the application goes to background the scanning also goes to background (creating scheduled jobs). For example


2019-07-20 01:23:46.880 13181-13181/package D/ScanJobScheduler: Scheduling ScanJob (job:208352940/package/org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob) to run every 300000 millis

Answer (score 0):

Huawei's EMUI operating system is a fork of Android that contains undocumented changes in standard Android behavior:

- Apps may not use the JobScheduler to run in the background indefinitely, causing the library's default Android 8+ background scanning mechanism to terminate.
- Bluetooth scans are sometimes blocked with the screen off using a secret algorithm that Huawei will not reveal.

**Bottom line: background beacon scanning simply is not reliable on Huawei devices.**

The library development team has attempted to independently reverse engineer Huawei's secret algorithm but has so far found no acceptable solutions.  See here: 
 https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/554

In the work above, this system level logcat line is known to be associated with blocking scans:

`E/Bth: G.GattService:App 'my_package_name' is scanning too frequently on screen off`

The work above was for EMUI 5.0-8.0, whereas the question above is for a P20 with EMUI 8.1.  The behavior sounds slightly different than described in the library issue above, so the secret scan blocking algorithm may have been modified between EMUI 8 and 8.1.  Any help in capturing system level logs to help characterize this behavior and adding them to the issue above would be appreciated.